# Geckodriver: How to use "moz:firefoxOptions" on node.config for selenium grid

Tags: automated-testing, grid, firefoxdriver, selenium3, geckodriver

I am running tests on selenium grid using nunit C# with:

- selenium-standalone-server: v3.3.1
- selenium webdriver: v3.3
- geckodriver: 0.15
- firefox: v52

Firefox is not installed on the default location and so I get following exception on running tests:

> Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I want to specify Firefox executable path on the capabilities section of `node.config` file of selenium grid. How do I do that with new geckodriver?

`firefox_binary` is now obsolete and it uses `"moz:firefoxOptions"`, but I don't know how to specify it in selenium node's config file.

This is what I am doing in the config file, but it's not working:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "moz:firefoxOptions": {
        "binary": "D:\\Browsers\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
        },
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ]
.........
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunatelly I found only workaround solution (e.g. if you need several different Firefox versions on a single station):

**nodeConfig_1.json**

```
{
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "version": "51",
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "marionette":true,
      "cleanSession": true
    },
...
```

**gridNode_1.cmd**

```
set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\51" 
java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Apps\Selenium\Grid\drivers\geckodriver.exe selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig_1.json
```

As you can guess, for other Firefox binaries you can use simmilar .cmd scripts.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the same solution. I could not find any documentation online on how to utilize .config file for this.